# Angular Directive Regex Alphanumeric Validation

Tags: regex, angular, typescript, validation, logic

I'm kinda new to Angular and Regex and I'm currently stuck with a problem. I need to create an Angular Directive that allows an input field to do the following:

1. Alphanumeric only
2. First input must be a letter
3. One space only between words
4. No special character

I've done numbers 1-3 my problem comes in #4. The input still accepts '_' , '`', '&', 'ˆ' and some other special characters. I just need to negate all special characters.

Here is my directive:

```
export class AlphaNumericFieldDirective{
  private regex: RegExp = new RegExp(/^[a-zA-Z]([a-zA-Z0-9]+ ?)*$/);
  private specialKeys: Array<string> = ['Backspace', 'Space', 'Tab', 'End', 'Home'];

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}

  @HostListener('keydown', ['$event'])
  onKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent) {
   if (this.specialKeys.indexOf(event.key) !== -1) {
      return;
   }
   let current: string = this.el.nativeElement.value;
   let next: string = current.concat(event.key);
   if (next && !String(next).match(this.regex)) {
      event.preventDefault();
   }
  }  
 }
```

And [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDtmG.png) is the sample output featuring some of the characters I want to negate

I would appreciate the help, thanks

Comment: The pattern does not match `&` or `,` https://regex101.com/r/awmy64/1

Comment: Sorry for the noob question, but what do you mean by the pattern does not match & or ,  ?

Comment: I have added an example link which shows the matches. The pattern `^[a-zA-Z](\w+ ?)*$` starts by matching a-zA-Z and optionally repeats matching 1+ word chars and an optional space.  It does not match "special" characters, but `_` is matched by `\w`

Comment: I tried changing `\w`  to `[a-zA-Z0-9]`. When inputting `_` it's now negated and is not shown in the field anymore, however others such as the acute, ampersand and caret symbols still appear.  Sorry just really have a hard time understanding regex.

Comment: Can you update the question with how you are using the code that does not work for you? That way people might be able to help you better.

Comment: Sorry, updated it and I've added the whole directive for reference.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is working for me.

```
    import { Directive, HostListener } from "@angular/core";
    
    @Directive({
        selector: "[appAlphabetOnly]",
    })
    export class AlphabetOnlyDirective {
    @HostListener("keydown", ["$event"]) public onKeydown(event: KeyboardEvent) {
        if (
            (event.keyCode >= 15 && event.keyCode <= 64) ||
            event.keyCode >= 123 ||
            (event.keyCode >= 96 && event.keyCode <= 105)
        ) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of relying on event.key, event.keyIdentifier, event.keyCode, etc. check the input value. The solution below is much simpler and works for browsers and webview, working with any framework. Then I provided some explanation and some test cases covering your requirements: Alphanumeric only, First input must be a letter, One space only between words, No special character.

OBS: if working with webview, replace event 'keydown' by your framework's event - for instance, 'ionInput', if working with Ionic.

**Directive**

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[alphanumeric]'
})
export class AlphanumericDirective {

  private _regEx = /^[a-zA-Z]\w*(\s[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*\s?$/;

  constructor(private _el: ElementRef) {}

  @HostListener("keydown", ["$event"]) 
  public onKeydown() {
    const value: string = this._el.nativeElement.value;
    if(!value) {
      return;
    }
    if (this._regEx.test(value)) {
      return;
    }
    /* replacing
     * ^[\d]+ one or more digits at the beginning of the string
     * (?<=\s)[\s] any whitespace preceded by another whitespace character ((?<=\s) is a positive lookbehind assertion)
     * [^\w\s] any non-word and non-whitespace character
     * [_] underscore character: some api's don't consider it as special char
     */
    this._el.nativeElement.value = value.replace(/^[\d]+|(?<=\s)[\s]|[^\w\s]|[_]/g, '');
  }

}
```

**Regex explanation**

- ^[a-zA-Z] - matches any letter (upper or lower case) in the beginning of the string
- \w* - matches zero or more alphanumeric characters
- (\s[a-zA-Z0-9]+)* - matches zero or more occurrences of a single space followed by one or more alphanumeric characters
- \s?$ - matches zero or one whitespace character at the end of the string at the end of the string

**Jasmine test cases**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AlphanumericDirective } from './alphanumeric.directive';

@Component({
  template: '<input type="text" alphanumeric>'
})
class TestComponent {}

describe('AlphanumericDirective', () => {
  let component: TestComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestComponent>;
  let inputEl: HTMLInputElement;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [TestComponent, AlphanumericDirective]
    });
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    inputEl = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input')).nativeElement;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should allow input that is alphanumeric and has one space between words', () => {
    inputEl.value = 'Hello 123 World';
    inputEl.dispatchEvent(new Event('keydown'));
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(inputEl.value).toEqual('Hello 123 World');
  });

  it('should allow only letters at the beginning of the string', () => {
    inputEl.value = '2Hello World';
    inputEl.dispatchEvent(new Event('keydown'));
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(inputEl.value).toEqual('Hello World');
  });

  it('should remove any non-alphanumeric characters', () => {
    inputEl.value = '!@#Hello 123 World%^&*()';
    inputEl.dispatchEvent(new Event('keydown'));
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(inputEl.value).toEqual('Hello 123 World');
  });

  it('should remove extra whitespace characters at the end', () => {
    inputEl.value = 'Hello 123 World    ';
    inputEl.dispatchEvent(new Event('keydown'));
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(inputEl.value).toEqual('Hello 123 World ');
  });

  it('should remove any whitespace characters after a single whitespace', () => {
    inputEl.value = 'Hello    123   World';
    inputEl.dispatchEvent(new Event('keydown'));
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(inputEl.value).toEqual('Hello 123 World');
  });
});
```